# Weird memory behaviour with array of structs

Tags: swift, memory-address, value-type

I am seeing a very weird (or at least weird to me) behaviour regarding memory addresses when playing around with structs in Swift.

I have the following code in a Playground:

```
func address(o: UnsafeRawPointer) -> Int {
    return Int(bitPattern: o)
}

struct Car {}

struct Garage {
    
    let cars: [Car]

    init() {
        var cars = [Car]()
        for _ in 0..<2 {
            cars.append(Car())
        }
        print(NSString(format: "%p", address(o: &cars[0])))
        self.cars = cars
    }
    
}

_ = Garage()
_ = Garage()
```

The console prints the same memory address both times for the first element of the cars array, even though they are initialized in completely different `Garage` instances:

```
0x7fff2f1102e0
0x7fff2f1102e0
```

Could someone shed some light on what's happening here?

Thanks!

Comment: Not really but you are printing the local variable so I guess the same memory is being reused. Printing the stored propety `cars` will give you unique addresses.

Comment: Yeah I assumed the same, just curious if this behaviour is the result some memory optimization.

Comment: The compiler can also create a temporary variable with the contents of `cars[0]` and pass *that* address to the function.

Comment: @MartinR Hmmm, I tried `cars.withUnsafeBufferPointer { bp in bp.baseAddress!.advanced(by: 0)))`, trying to replicate the semantics that `&cars[0]` would have in C (it would be a pointer expression equivalent to `(cars + 0)`, i.e. a pointer into the buffer), yet I still get the same address both times. Why could that be?

Comment: @Alexander: Perhaps because the values are nowhere stored, so if the second Garage is instantiated the first one does not exist anymore. What happens if you assign the values to “real” variables instead of `_` ?

Comment: Yes, this the kind of memory optimization a modern compiler is supposed to do. The two *Garage* instances are not used at the same time. So it would be a waste of memory to allocate them in separate locations on the stack.

Comment: @MartinR Doing that made them different.

Comment: @Codo What surprised me is that `cars` has a heap-allocated buffer, not stack-allocated. I was surprised to see that the allocation repeatedly hit the same address, though keeping both instances alive simultaneously did make them different

Comment: As it turns out, the reason is even simpler than a clever compiler. See my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The printed addresses are hint: `0x7fff2f1102e0` is likely a stack address, not the address of an object on the heap.

So does Swift allocate the `Car` array on the stack? No it doesn't.

However, `cars[0]` is an operation that returns a **copy** of the `Car` instance. That's because `Car` is a `struct` and has value semantics. And the copy is on the stack.

So `address(o: &cars[0])` returns the address of the copied instance on the stack. Since two consecutive calls of `init()` are likely to use the stack in the same way, they will return the same address.